# Lenovo ACIP issue - several modifications of GRUB have not worked

Tags: grub2, system-installation, lenovo, acpi

Have a Lenovo Thinkcenter MT-M 8700-D7U that is hanging on ACPI. I've made the edit to this and other systems in the past. This particular Lenovo is not accepting the edits, therefore it will not install (hangs) Ubuntu 20.04. I was able to get Ubuntu 17 installed, did all updates and restarted the standard ACIP edits to grub.

The result of this issue is that the Lenovo system will run well but it won't shutdown properly. It gets to the point of shutting down the system and provides a SYSTEM DOWN statement but does not turn off the power. `122.425923] reboot: System Halted`.

I was able to get 17.x installed, but ran all updates to bring it to 20.04. I did various updates with no luck to be able to fully shutdown the computer (OS error and power left ON). I just started over with the Ubuntu 20.10 DVD. It runs the basic install (white text) to the disk drive and hangs on the first presence of the purple desktop (mouse hovering lower right quadrant). I did an edit to the bootstrap and instructed it to boot with the following settings: `priority=high acpi=off acpi=force`. Hitting F10 will allow it to start the boot process, but that is where it hangs on the purple desktop with no icons.

Comment: Can you update your question to include some specifics, such as: *which* Lenovo device you are trying to install Ubuntu on, *which* version of Ubuntu (20.04? 20.10? Desktop? Server?), and *where* this issue is being seen? You mention you can't install the OS, then you say the system does not shut down properly. Clarity will help someone offer specific suggestions.

Comment: regarding shutdown, once the OS (previous version 17 that was installed) was instructed to shutdown (from icon or command line) the OS will go through its process to close. A final statement will be at the top left of the monitor which is the 122. statement above. It does change and the Power on the computer does not turn OFF.  On depressing the power button the system closes instantly but is a slow process of Starting the computer the next time.

Comment: tried fresh install OEM version - same issue being hung on purple scree with ROUND cursor at bottom right corner of monitor - no apparent response to the keyboard or mouse